# How do I get started with Podio API Keys

Tags: api-key, podio

I'm trying to understand how I can make API calls and fetch data from Podio. And once I have the API Key, how I can use that in a XMLHttpRequest and fetch data.

I've read the help articles on Podio but its all confusing to me. Any help in this direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably start here: https://developers.podio.com/api-key to create new key.

Then read https://developers.podio.com/authentication and follow directions there on how to make first API call to Podio.